# decomposition according to embeddings

Tags: linear-algebra, nt.number-theory

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $L/\mathbb{Q}$ a finite extension. Assume that $V$ is equipped with a structure of $L$-vector space. Then there is a decomposition 
$$
V \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{C}=\bigoplus_{\sigma \in Hom(L, \mathbb{C})} V_\sigma
$$

A) What is the best way to think of that?

I guess it has something to do with the fact that
$L \otimes_\mathbb{Q} \mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{Hom(L, \mathbb{C})}$...

B) Is it true that all $V_\sigma$ have the same dimension? If so, how to prove it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A) $V \otimes_{\mathbb Q} L \otimes_L {\mathbb C}$

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit more? what about question B?

Comment: When you write $V_\sigma$, do you mean $V \otimes_{L, \sigma} \mathbb{C}$?  The latter notation makes the equidimensionality clear.

Comment: If $L=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ then $V_\sigma$ is the subspace of $V_\mathbb{C}$ where $\alpha v=\sigma(\alpha)v$ (this is independent from $\alpha$). Is that the same as $V \otimes_{L, \sigma} \mathbb{C}$?